# hide datepicker using its type

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the below code to Hide TextBox , Label and Dropdownlist. But how would i hide a datepicker ? can i do the same for datepicker in the below code ?

```
 If (TypeOf ctrTexbox Is TextBox) Then
        If isMasked Then
            CType(ctrLabel, Label).Visible = True
            CType(ctrTexbox, TextBox).Visible = False
        Else
            CType(ctrLabel, Label).Visible = False
            CType(ctrTexbox, TextBox).Visible = True
        End If
    ElseIf (TypeOf ctrTexbox Is DropDownList) Then
        If isMasked Then
            CType(ctrLabel, Label).Visible = True
            CType(ctrTexbox, DropDownList).Visible = False
        Else
            CType(ctrLabel, Label).Visible = False
            CType(ctrTexbox, DropDownList).Visible = True
        End If
```

html for datepicker

```
  <BDP:BasicDatePicker Style="z-index: 205; left: 312px" ID="dtp" runat="server" width="250px" SelectedDate="1989-01-01" DateFormat="dd/MMM/yyyy">                                                                                
  <TextBoxStyle CssClass="inputbox" Width="250px" /></BDP:BasicDatePicker>
```

Comment: on code behind, `ID.visible = false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can, as [`BasicDatePicker`](http://www.basicdatepicker.com/documentation/index.html) is also derived from the same `WebControl` class :

```
ElseIf (TypeOf ctrTexbox Is BasicFrame.WebControls.BasicDatePicker) Then
    If isMasked Then
        CType(ctrLabel, Label).Visible = True
        CType(ctrTexbox, BasicFrame.WebControls.BasicDatePicker).Visible = False
    Else
        CType(ctrLabel, Label).Visible = False
        CType(ctrTexbox, BasicFrame.WebControls.BasicDatePicker).Visible = True
    End If
```